# How to pass an Arc clone to a closure?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker, trait-objects

I'm trying to write a closure that uses an `Arc` by cloning it. Ideally I'd like to have the clone inside the closure, but I'm kinda forced to pass the original `Arc`, which might be the reason I'm getting the error:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Condvar;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::VecDeque;

type Fifo<T> = Arc<(Mutex<VecDeque<T>>, Condvar)>;

fn executor(f: Box<dyn Fn()>) {
    f();
}

fn main() {
    let a = Fifo::<u8>::new(
        (Mutex::new(VecDeque::new()), Condvar::new())
    );
    
    let r = Box::new(||{
        let f = a.clone();
        f.0.lock().unwrap().push_back(0);
    });
    executor(r);
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:19:17
   |
18 |     let r = Box::new(||{
   |                      -- value captured here
19 |         let f = a.clone();
   |                 ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
22 |     executor(r);
   |              - cast requires that `a` is borrowed for `'static`
23 | }
   | - `a` dropped here while still borrowed

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I thought changing to

```
let r = Box::new(||{
    //let f = a.clone();
    a.0.lock().unwrap().push_back(0);
});
```

would force the closure to decide to clone `a`, therefore fixing the problem, but I get the same error.

How can I pass an `Arc` to a closure?

Comment: Clone the Arc _outside_ the closure, and use a `move` closure to force the move: `let r = { let a = a.clone(); Box::new(move || { a.0.lock().unwrap().push_back(0); }) };` Also note that Rust never decides to clone values automatically, in contrast to C++. A closure can automatically decide whether to capture by move or reference, and since you don't consume the captured value, it decided on reference, which we had to override with the `move` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clone the `Arc` outside the closure and then `move` the clone into the closure. Example:

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Condvar;
use std::sync::Mutex;

type Fifo<T> = Arc<(Mutex<VecDeque<T>>, Condvar)>;

fn executor(f: Box<dyn Fn()>) {
    f();
}

fn main() {
    let a = Fifo::<u8>::new((Mutex::new(VecDeque::new()), Condvar::new()));

    let f = a.clone();
    let r = Box::new(move || {
        f.0.lock().unwrap().push_back(0);
    });

    executor(r);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aabe3a3efdfbb80db3a5773af8eb4568)